# Python: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, eclipse-neon

I'm creating a client to server based chat client and every time I setup a server and a client, the server keeps listening for a connection and when the client attempts to connect this error appears `[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`, however the server still listens for a connection. I'm using python version 3.6.1

**Script**

```
import socket
import threading

clients = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

mode = input("Enter 1 for server mode and enter 2 for client mode")
if mode == "1":

    def get_ip():
        try:
            stest = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            stest.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
            IP = stest.getsockname()[0]
        except:
            IP = '127.0.0.1'
        finally:
            stest.close()
        return IP
    print("IP: " + get_ip())
    s.bind((get_ip(), 7999))
    s.setblocking(0)

    print("Waiting for connection")
    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if data.decode() == "Quit":
                quitmsg = str(addr) + " has quit the chat."
                clients.remove(addr)
                for client in clients:
                    s.sendto(quitmsg.encode("utf-8"), client)
                break
            elif data:
                print(data)
                if addr not in clients:
                    clients.append(addr)
                    print(clients[0])
                for client in clients:
                    print(client)
                    s.sendto(data, client)
        except:
            pass
        s.close()


elif mode == "2":
    while True:
        try:
            ip = input("Enter in an ip address")
            socket.inet_aton(ip)
        except socket.error:
            print("Invalid IPv4 address")
            continue
        while True:
            try:
                port = int(input("Enter in port number"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid Port Number")
                continue
            break
        addr = (ip, port)
        break
    s.connect(addr)

    def recvmsg():
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            if data:
                print(data.decode())

    recv = threading.Thread(name="recvmsg", target=recvmsg)
    recv.daemon = True
    recv.start()

    while True:
        string = input(">>")
        s.send(string.encode("utf-8"))
        if str(string) == "Quit":
            break

    s.close()
    print("Disconnected from chat")
```

[Server Waiting For connection even after client can't connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9rf.png)

[Client Failed to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAPUl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your server is not on the local network, make sure port 7999 is open and forwarded on its access point. Otherwise the packets will just be dropped by the router. If it is on your local network, still try forwarding. Also according to https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=7999 the port has been used by a worm, so maybe permanently closed on the other network?? Unlikely but possible.

Comment: At first I thought that the router would be in AP Isolation mode but then I tried it on my loop-back interface 127.0.0.1 and got the same response.

Comment: Hmm, could also be a firewall issue? Try looking at logs

Comment: I don't think so it was working normally when I had the client and the server functionalities in both different scripts. Also I run two different instances of the same script if that matters.

Comment: Maybe run them on different computers and see if it works?

Comment: I dont think thats the issue, it was working normally when they were in two seperate scripts running on the same pc.

Comment: For me the server doesn't actually react to connection, the client doesn't throw any errors. Try in python 2.7? change your inputs to raw_inputs. Other than that I can't see an issue